# Could not find "store" in either the context or props with React.createElement

Tags: reactjs, backbone.js, react-redux

Context: We're starting to migrate a Backbone.js app and have created a sort of barrier view between backbone and React.

The relevant part of the Backbone view is as follows:

```js
{
    ...
    render: function() {
      const component = React.createElement(this.component, this.getComponentProps());
      const rootComponent = React.createElement(Provider, { store }, component);
      this.reactComponent = ReactDOM.render(rootComponent, this.el);
      ...
    },
    ...
}
```

The React component I'm attempting to connect looks like this:

```js
define(function(require) {
  const React = require('react');
  const { connect } = require('react-redux');

  class SomeConnectedComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>hello world</span>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({});
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({});

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeConnectedComponent);
});
```

I then pass `SomeConnectedComponent` as `this.component` in my `RView` that I define. The element creation in the `RView` wraps `this.component` in `<Provider>` so that it is a direct descendent. The correct component hierarchy is confirmed in the React DevTools when I **DO NOT** use `connect`. The issue is that when use `connect` and I load the page I get the following error:

```
react-redux.js:1119 Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(SomeConnectedComponent)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(SomeConnectedComponent)".
at invariant$2 (react-redux.js:1119)
at new Connect (react-redux.js:1320)
at react-dom.js:4698
at measureLifeCyclePerf (react-dom.js:4479)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (react-dom.js:4697)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (react-dom.js:4688)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4591)
at Object.mountComponent (react-dom.js:11409)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (react-dom.js:4774)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (react-dom.js:4661)
```

I have tried loading the page without the `connect()` (which works just fine) and using the React DevTools I was able to confirm that the `<Provider>` component was passed the `store` prop and that it is correctly populated with my `store`. The store also appears correctly in the Redux DevTools so I can be certain it has been created.

I'm pretty much at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not clear from what you've included, but when you're using `SomeConnectedComponent` is that a direct descendant of your `Provider`?

Comment: @ZaidCrouch Sorry, just edited to be more clear that I'm fairly confident the component hierarchy is correct.